# DOMPDF Stuck on Letter Paper Size

Tags: php, cakephp, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF on a little web app I'm building. It's working great apart from it's stuck on the default paper size of 'US Letter' no matter where I change it.

Any ideas?

```
// dompdf_config.inc.php
def("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_PAPER_SIZE", "a4");
```

Comment: See that this is answered, but ... the default paper size set in the config not honored?

Comment: it was being ignored yes ... strange I know ... you had this?

Comment: I haven't experienced this, but if it is a persistent problem it's something we'll want to look into (I work on the project).

Comment: It does look like dompdf ignores the default size and uses letter. The default is probably being superseded during initialization. I've posted a [bug report](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/687), which you can follow if you want to know when the issue is addressed. As noted in the accepted answer you can manually specify the page size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you correctly calling the 'set_paper' method in your pdf creation as follows :

```
$dompdf->set_paper(DEFAULT_PDF_PAPER_SIZE, 'portrait');
```

Furthermore, you can define your own paper size if this is still not working using something along the lines of the following :

```
$paper_size = array(0,0,360,360);
$dompdf->set_paper($paper_size);
```

Comment: Ahhh shocking N00B mistake I just had:
$this->pdf->core->set_paper('a4');

Comment: How about setting the Creator? So I can change it to my app's name instead of "DOMPDF"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a creator, i'm not sure if the built in functionality is there for that option. I do know you can set the PDF title and author with something such as this "$dompdf->add_info('Author', 'Author Name Here');" So there may be a 'Creator' option but I can't be 100% sure without testing any code.

Comment: In fact after a quick look through the dompdf.cls.php file you can see that at line 911 the supported labels are shown which are 'author', 'keywords' and 'description'. But keeping DOMPDF as the creator is a good way of supporting such a fantastic and free library.

Comment: Oh I know that, I wouldn't take them out, but append. It's only for an internal web app anyway. See what you make of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682119/font-glyph-outline-error-when-using-webfonts-with-dompdf) too good sir?

Answer (score 8):

The above did not help me still stuck on Letter The following did work (from DOMPDF FAQ)

```
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait");
```

Comment: I ended up switching libs to WkHtmlToPdf ... had a look into that? It's pretty comprehensive, and supports a lot more css than other engines.